# Defining a minimum webpage size until scrollbar appears (globally)

Tags: html, css

I want to define a global width for all of my pages (e.g. using a wrapper, ...). If the browser is resized below this pre-defined minimum value, the scroll bar should appear and a further resizing of the images/text or splitting up a navigation bar into two horizontal lines, is not done.
Any html/CSS code is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look here:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp or research about "responsive css" or "css media query"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query css for the same::
EG::

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .wrapper {overflow: scroll;}
}
```

Comment: Sry, but this is not working as I intended. I already have html files, DWTs and my css done. Since I have text, tables, images, navigation bars, ... I want to set a lower border from which a scroll bar appears. Vertically there is now adjustment made automatically. I want the same for the width ONLY with a "do that, when browser is (horizontally) resized to value smaller than X". The @media commands are new to me. I tried <div class="wrapper">